# Problema ao renderizar porcentagem pequena no PieChartModel no Primefaces;

Tags: java, primefaces-3.5

Estou gerando um gráfico geralmente sem problemas, só ocorre com porcentagens menores, mostrando a 'fatia' corretamente, porém não é exibido o valor dessa porcentagem.
Tentei fazer a alteração do diâmetro do piechart, como vi que é possível no xhtml(no showcase é feito no Java, porém a propriedade de parâmetros não aparece para ser setada para mim).
Alguém já passou por isso, ou poderia me auxiliar?
Obs: utilizo Primefaces 3.5.

Segue abaixo o código que utilizo e a imagem do gráfico:

java:

```
this.graficoAteste = new PieChartModel();
...
graficoAteste.set("Sim", 33);
graficoAteste.set("Não", 2);
graficoAteste.set("Parcial", 1);
graficoAteste.set("Não Atestado", 0);
```

xhtml:

```
<p:pieChart id="graficoAteste" widgetVar="grafico_pizza"
value="#{graficoAtestePeriodoBean.graficoAteste}"
legendPosition="e" fill="true" showDataLabels="true"
title="#{msg.grafico_ateste_por_periodo}"
style="width:450px;height:350px" sliceMargin="6" diameter="200"
rendered="#{graficoAtestePeriodoBean.graficoAteste != null}" />
```

[image: imagem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opa, encontrei a solução para o meu caso.
A questão é que o `PieChart` do `Primefaces` utiliza uma biblioteca `JQuery` chamada `JQPlot` que, por padrão, não renderiza porcentagens abaixo de 3%.
Vendo isso, tive que sobrescrever alguns parametros via `Javascript` e utilizar o parametro `extender` no meu `Piechart` recebendo esse `Javascript`.
Ficando assim:

Piechart:

```
<p:pieChart id="graficoAteste" widgetVar="grafico_pizza"
                    value="#{graficoAtestePeriodoBean.graficoAteste}"
                    legendPosition="e" fill="true" showDataLabels="true"
                    title="#{msg.grafico_ateste_por_periodo}"
                    style="width:450px;height:350px" sliceMargin="6" diameter="200"
                    rendered="#{graficoAtestePeriodoBean.graficoAteste != null}" extender="ext" />
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ext() {
        this.cfg.seriesDefaults.rendererOptions.dataLabelThreshold = 1;
        this.cfg.seriesDefaults.rendererOptions.dataLabelPositionFactor = 0.6;
    }
</script>
```

Onde `dataLabelThreshold` é a porcentagem mínima a ser renderizada e `dataLabelPositionFactor` é a distancia do centro do gráfico que o número deve ficar(0 a 1).